# Using Logcat to find where the line of code originates from

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

```
Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2
```

Hello,

This is using the Linphone source code that has been imported into Eclipse.

I am trying find where the `Push notification received` line of code is. However, I can't find it anywhere in the Linphone source code. As I didn't write that log statement myself I don't know where it is.

I would like to debug where the push notification is first received.

Is there anyway finding this line of code from logcat?

[image]

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is on line 50 of GCMService.java as seen in this file in the repo :

https://github.com/viv/linphone-android/blob/master/src/org/linphone/gcm/GCMService.java