# Tracing logcat entry to originating code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I'm working with a rather complex build from another dev company who is no longer supporting the code that I'm working with.

I keep getting a debug line showing up in the logcat that I'd like to trace back to the originating code. There is a fairly unique string that it prints - `Running now.`

I've searched for how to trace the logcat back to the source line and found answers like:

- [Using logcat to find where line originates from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699525/using-logcat-to-find-where-the-line-of-code-originates-from) which doesn't have an explaination, just a very narrow answer
- [Creating a double click link in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067528/is-there-any-way-to-access-automatically-any-log-in-logcat-by-a-double-click/12242852#12242852) which has some great code, but I would need to modify the `Log` line, which would mean finding the line anyway

Is there is simple solution to either trace back the logcat line to the originating code OR search all files in a package for a string of text (using the GUI, not Java)?

Comment: You have all the Java code files and you need to find a text in them, is it?

Comment: Yes, I have all the Java files and the logcat entry with a string of text that I want to find. Anything more elegant than a Find in the workspace?

Comment: I guess you could use the `grep` command if you're on Linux.

Comment: Also if it is a proper dev company code, their tags would usually be a constant name which is very identical to the class name. As much as I've come across, they usually mention the tag like `public static final String TAG = "class_name"` and use it throughout the `class`.

Comment: They use a custom wrapper for the `Log` which disguises the class name, so it's unfortunately not that simple.